# chrome fails to load SOME scripts & stylesheets with ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE (for a flask app on linux (debian))

Tags: google-chrome, flask, firefox

I have a flask app running on Linux and working correctly under firefox.
For chrome, it only works if the cache is disabled!?
But i want my website to work correctly without every user having to disable caching.

This is how the template HTML header looks:

```
<!-- Bootstrap & CSS  -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/fontawesome-free-6.1.1-web/css/all.min.css" >
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/app.css">

{% if css_file %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ css_file }}">
{% endif %}

<!-- JQuery -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/bootstrap/css/jquery-ui.css" >
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/bootstrap/css/jquery-ui.min.css" >
<script type="text/javascript" src="/bootstrap/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/bootstrap/js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap JS -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- local JS -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/language.js"></script>
{% if js_file %}
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ js_file }}"></script>
{% endif %}
```

And yes all files exist in the static folder (because it works in firefox)
And flask is initiated like this (which is the default):

```
# create and configure the app
app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='', static_folder='static', template_folder='templates')
```

Chrome (dev tools->network):
[image]

Chrome (dev tools->network)(with cache disabled), same for firefox (cache enabled):
[image]

Could someone give me a hint on how to analyse further what the problem is?
Could it be related to the response of flask for static files?
Or do I have the wrong header order?
Or is it a problem with the scripts/ stylesheets, do they have the wrong configuration?
So the question is how to fix this for chrome without disabling the cache.

And no I do not have Adblock or similar addons installed.

Comment: I have the same problem - Flask app + Google Chrome (I would say, the problem appeared since update to version 100, but I'm not sure).
Same behaviour - when loading page without cache, it's loaded correctly, after that I hit F5 on the same page (load with cache) and it loads only HTML (without resources - CSS, JS, images, ... or partially) resources are attemted to load, but fail with net::ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE (no response at all, no response headers). The problem is also in Incognito window (no addons).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Flask 304 response on reload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71890593/python-flask-304-response-on-reload)

Answer (score 1):

I think this issue related to Chrome, but I don't have time to dig deeper into  it. My workaround is include `no-store` in `Cache-Control` header:

```py
@app.after_request
def add_header(response):
    response.headers['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache, no-store'
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit late but had the same issue and it got fixed by upgrading flask, you can check what needs to be upgraded with

```
pip list --outdated
```

if you have multiple outdated packages (this will upgrade everything)

```
pip freeze | %{$_.split('==')[0]} | %{pip install --upgrade $_}
```